# Зло, золото, злак

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Здесь уже обсуждался вопрос по поводу выражения "злачное место". Но меня интересует немного другой аспект. Слова "зло", "золото (злато)" и "злак" - есть ли между ними что-то общее? Я еще могу допустить, что "злак" и "злато" - родственные слова из-за цвета колоса, золотистого, почти золотого. "Зло" и "злато" - разве что из серии "люди гибнут за металл". "Зло" и "злак" - вспоминаем то самое "злачное место". Но все это мне кажется притянутым за уши.
Как на самом деле обстоит ситуация с этими словами? Однокоренные они или просто созвучные?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зло и добро - два полюса жизни, и осознавались они и противопоставлялись друг другу  вместе с развитием человеческого общества.

Злой - общеславянское слово индоевропейского характера, но исходное значение корня - это кривой, изогнутый (он сохранилось в осет. zul - кривой). В современном обществе  "злой" - это недоброжелательный, проникнутый враждой и ненавистью, сердитый, свирепый,  лютый,  язвительный. Все дурное и плохое связано со злом,  и зло понималось обобщенно уже с 11 века -  как низкая, порочная, враждебная человеку материя.

На другой стороне добро  - всё хорошее, положительное, направленное на благо.  Добрый  - общеславянское слово, его изначальное значение - большой, крепкий, вошедший в добу (в свою  пору, в свое время). Сначала добрый предмет был просто годным, пригожим, подходящим, а добро как  милосердие стало осознаваться только позже, с прогрессом и развитием общественных отношений.

Слова золото и злак - этимологические родственники, такой же корень и в словах желтый и зеленый (и.-е. корень ghel - янтарно-желтый, сравнить: gold (англ.) - золото).  Золото буквально - это желтый металл, злак - зеленый побег. К злу они отношения не имеют.

Comment: А как так получилось, что "ghel" обозначает два разных цвета? И связано ли с этим корнем слово "гель"?

Answer (score 2):

Слова **золото** и **злато** в действительности имеют одно и то же лексическое значение. В данном случае присутствует чередование ОЛО/ЛА. В старославянском языке существовали такие слова, которые имели такое чередование, например: золото (слав. злато), врата (слав. ворота).

Этимология слова зло: Происходит от праслав. , от кот. в числе прочего произошли: др.-русск., ст.-слав. зълъ, зъла, зъло (др.-греч. πονηρός, κακός), русск. зло, злой, укр. злий, болг. зъл, нареч. зле, сербохорв. за̏о, зла̏, зло̏, словенск. zǝ̀l, zlà, чешск., словацк. zlý, польск. złу, в.-луж., н.-луж. złу «злой». Родственно лит. atžū́las, atžūlùs «черствый, бесчеловечный», įžūlùs «надоедливый, наглый, грубый», авест. zūrah-, ср. р. «несправедливость», нов.-перс. zūr «фальшивый, ложь»; с другим чередованием: лит. žvalùs «проворный», žvilavo — 3. л. ед. ч. прош. вр. «кланялся», латышск. zvel^t, zvel̨u, zvēlu «катать, наклонять», др.-инд. hvárati, hválati «идет кривыми путями, петляет, спотыкается, падает», авест. zbaraiti — то же, осет. æwzær «плохой».